# What kind of framewoks Spring is?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I want to start learning about the Spring framework, and I was wondering what type of framewoks it is.

I googled about it but I didn't found anything helpful.

for example, JSF is a presentation framework, and Hibernate is a persistence framework.

Comment: You should really work on your googling skills. There is an incredibly large amount of documentation written about Spring, beginning with Spring's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a general purpose framework, in particular it provides support for:

- Dependency Injection
- Aspect-Oriented Programming
- MVC
- RESTful web service

It also gives support for JDBC, JPA, JMS and much more.

This means that you can include the framework in you project and use it classes for the different elements just reported.
It's not easy to describe all you can do and the benefits in few lines. Try looking what each of these element offer to understand the power of this framework.